# can there be an ascii control character inside a unicode character

Tags: unicode, ascii

i am parsing binary data with mixed ascii and unicode characters. here is an example:

A..|B....|C..

where 2 dots represent two bytes for a unicode character.

My question is.. Is it safe to parse this data using the field separator character (|) (0x7c). Or there could be a chance that 0x7c could appear in one of the unicode bytes?

like

A.||B....|C..

wherein the 2nd and 3rd byte are actually part of a unicode character. If I parse using the | as a separator it would yield wrong values. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression “unicode character” appears to mean “UTF-16 encoding of a character” (judging from the comments). Then the answer is that any Ascii control character, and any Ascii character, may appear there (more exactly, that one of the bytes of the UTF-16 encoded data may coincide with a byte representing a character in the Ascii code). Trivially, the UTF-16 encoding of an Ascii character consists of the 0 byte and a byte containing the Ascii code value. And, for example, the UTF-16 encoding of U+7C7C CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-7C7C (xiān) consists of *two* 0x7C bytes.

Note that VERTICAL LINE ”|” U+007C (0x7C in Ascii) is not a control character in any normal terminology. [Ascii control characters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) are 0x00 to 0x1F and 0x7F. (The SPACE 0x20 is sometimes described as being both a control character and a graphic character, but this is confusing and generally avoided nowadays.)

To get help with your parsing problem, you should specify the format of the data more exactly. The format seems to be poorly designed, since it *cannot* be parsed unambiguously, if the idea is (as it seems) that an Ascii character is followed by a variable amount of data in UTF-16 encoding. For example, in “A..|B....|C..”, you cannot really know (without additional rules) that what you show here as “|B” (bytes 0x7C 0x42) is not actually UTF-16 data, representing U+7C42 or U+427C (depending on endianness of UTF-16).

Comment: thanks jukka. ok i'll coordinate with the vendor of the device. thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Unicode encoding.

If you are using UTF8, no problem

UTF16, UTF32 (maybe others) may have the byte that represents a '|' in them.

Given that your file is certainly not UT16 and not UTF32, it likely will work.

Comment: thanks chux.one character is represent by two bytes. i believe it's utf16. then if thats the case, | is not reliable

Comment: Sorry - thought the "A.." was 3 bytes.  But there is support for UTF16, which takes 2 bytes (sometimes 4) per "character".  Not sure of your target computer language.

Comment: Yes you are correct. A.. are 3 bytes. It is mixed. "A" is 1 byte and .. are 2. In my example A..|B....|C.. is actually 13 bytes. Makes me wonder if | has any use at all.

Comment: This implies your Unicode encoding is UTF8 and 0x7c  should only appear when it is a `|`.